# Confusing solutions for definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area enclosed by the curves at the given interval:

$y = sec^2(\frac {πx}3)$ and $y = x^{1/3}$, $-1\leq x \leq 1$

I integrate: $$\int_{-1}^1 (sec^2(\frac {πx}3) -x^{1/3})dx = \left[\frac 3π tan(\frac {πx}3) -\frac 34 x^{4/3}\right]_{-1}^1 = \frac {6\sqrt{3}}π $$

My solution gives $\frac {6\sqrt{3}}π$. The same solution I get in Desmos. However Wolframalpha gives me $\frac {6\sqrt{3}}π - \frac34 (1 + \sqrt[3]{-1})$

I do not understand:

- Why do I get a solution when graphically the two curves show no
  common area between the given interval.
- Why does Wolframalpha gives $\sqrt[3]{-1})$ when the order of evaluation of $(-1)^{4/3}\ \bigr(((-1)^4)^{1/3} = 1^{1/3} = 1 \ or\ ((-1)^{1/3})^4 = (-1)^4 = 1 \bigr)$ appears to give $1$ in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't we get a solution? For each $x\in[-1,1]$, $x^{\frac13}\leqslant\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi x}3\right)$. So, that integral is the area of the region above the first function and below the second one.

Concerning WolframAlpha, it's just because it “thinks” that, when $x<0$, $x^{\frac13}=\sqrt[3]{\lvert x\rvert}\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}3\right)$.

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thank you for the answer. I somehow thought an area should be formed by crossing graphs.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see 
$$\sec^2 \big( \tfrac{\pi x}{3} \big) \geq x^{1/3} \quad \textrm{ for } -1\leq x\leq 1$$
and the area it is also enclosed by the vertical lines $ x = -1 $ and $ x = 1 $ :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a typical problem with $\color{red}{\sqrt[3]x}$.

What I suppose that you typed is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sec(Pi+x%2F3)%5E2-x%5E(1%2F3)+from+x%3D-1+to+x%3D1).

Instead type [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sec(Pi+x%2F3)%5E2-cuberoot(x)+from+x%3D-1+to+x%3D1) which will give the correct result. This is why they introduced the function $\color{red}{\text{cuberoot}}$.